# Transpose a simple Access Table

Tags: ms-access, vba, transpose

Similar questions to this have been asked on SO, but none that I have been able to apply to my situation.

I've created this simply sum query to count the number of values I have for each column in my `2 Tag Core Count` query:

```
SELECT Count([CORE_DATA].[TAG NUMBER]) AS [TAG NUMBER], 
Count([CORE_DATA].[TAG STATUS]) AS [TAG STATUS], 
Count([CORE_DATA].[UNIT NUMBER]) AS [UNIT], 
Count([CORE_DATA].[FUNCTIONAL CLASS]) AS [FUNCTIONAL CLASS] 
    FROM CORE_DATA;
```

This works perfectly fine. Except, for my situation, I require a transpose of the resulting table. E.g. Fields 1 to contain the column titles from the above query `TAG NUMBER, TAG STATUS, UNIT NUMBER and FUNCTIONAL CLASS` and Field 2 to contain the corresponding count.

How can you go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This worked for me

```
SELECT 'TAG NUMBER' as [Attribute Value], [TAG NUMBER] as Count
FROM [2 Tag Core Count]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TAG STATUS' as [Attribute Value], [TAG STATUS] as Count
FROM [2 Tag Core Count]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'UNIT' as [Attribute Value], [UNIT] as Count
FROM [2 Tag Core Count]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FUNCTIONAL CLASS' as [Attribute Value], [FUNCTIONAL CLASS] as Count
FROM [2 Tag Core Count];
```